# Why does my html file no longer use my css file when uploaded?

Tags: html, css, upload, web

Alright, here's my problem. I have 4 files. One is HTML, One is CSS, one is my own Javascript, and one is the latest jQuery. They go together to form a page. When I load the HTML file from a folder on my computer, everything works. I then uploaded it to a website: http://mtgchaos.site11.com/ and while the javascript works fine, the CSS doesn't seem to be in there at all. All of the files are still in the same directory. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="chaos.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Chaos.js"></script>
    <title>MTG Chaos Roller</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="button">
    <input type="submit" value="Roll Chaos">
    <input type="submit" value="Roll EnchantWorldLand">
    <input type="submit" value="Roll PersonaLand">
    <input type="submit" value="Roll WackyLand">
    <input type="submit" value="Roll DurgsLand">
    <input type="submit" value="Roll PunishmentLand">
</div>
<div class="texmex"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}
.button {
    text-align: center;
}
p {
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the file you uploaded has capital c

try this
http://mtgchaos.site11.com/Chaos.css
change the code to

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Chaos.css"/>
```

and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Your server throws a 404 when you try and access the css file directly.  This usually means that the css file on the server is missing.  Re-upload the file to the server into the path it was in before and then view the page again.

I would venture to guess this would fix your issue.

Comment: It does not. The css file is definitely there. I even edited it directly on the server.